# Difference in the database opened through mysql console in wamp and opening mysql through command prompt

Tags: mysql, database, wamp

I have wamp server, it has the option of phpmyadmin and mysql console among with other options. when I open mysql console from this option, and give the command.
    show databases;

I get a list of various databases.

Whereas, if open the mysql command prompt form the windows command prompt, I dont see those databases.

Why is this difference??

Please refer the attached screenshot[image: screenshot]

Comment: You're probably accessing the database using a different username, with different permissions.

Comment: @Barmar: What does that mean? Where can I change the username to match that of wamp?? And I am still a learner, please don't downvote the questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Barmar is correct.

When you run the mysql.exe processor the correct syntax is to enter a userid to the mysql.exe It then asks you for the password.

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

The is the syntax that the menu item `MySQL Console` uses behind the scenes.

As there is no password on the `root` user account after a install of MySQL Server the `MySQL Console` command will just login using the `root` userid and you are the super user.

When you do it as you have i.e. just entering the processor name WITHOUT a userid

```
mysql
```

You get logged in with a guest account that has little or no privilages, so you only see the databases that that guest account is allowed to see.

basically WAMPServer makes installing these complex tool very easy, however that does not mean they are simple tools. You are going to have to apply yourself to learning how to use them properly now.  This seems like a good place to start [The manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/)

Comment: Thanks for the elucid response.